# extend timeout for adding a windows printer connection

Tags: windows, vbscript, timeout, smb, network-printers

For example doing this:

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\server\printer"
```

If this is done during a slow login, the printer may never appear.  I believe there is some kind of (smb? cifs?) timeout.  Is there a way to extend the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the problem.  I would delete my profile, and then login again and the network printer would fail to add.  I figured out that something called Client-Side Rendering or CSR (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/02/10/ws2008-client-side-rendering/) was adding the printer at the same time and clobbering it.